# Custom message handler with attribute based routing is not working for Web API 2

Tags: c#, webapi2, message-handlers

I have a Message Handler in my Web API 2 project which change the url to a different path. Such as url `"root/controller/somevalue/detials"` will be changed to `"root/controller/2/details"`. Where "somevalue" or 2 is a parameter for the action method.

I have placed the message handler registration code before calling 
`config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`
Message handler is registered as 
`config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyHandler());`

For normal route mapping it is working fine.
But if I enable attribute based routing then the message handler is called and changed the url but action method is hit with the same "somevalue" not "2".

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RouteAttribute`, then you can have Route value like this for capturing somevalue :

```
Route["details/{somevalue}"]
public IHttpActionResult MyCustiomApiMethod(string somevalue)
{
    //return 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you are pointed out. But the problem is the "somevalue" is encrypted and I am using  that message handler to decrypt it. So the some value should be a number after decrypting it.

Comment: Have you used attribute like above? enclosed variable in parenthesis {} which you want to capture

Comment: OP has the route as `somevalue/details` but your answer has `details/somevalue` (positions swaped)